# How can close the extjs desktop.window and then open it

Tags: extjs, desktop

I want to close the window and then open it.
I just do `window.close` and then I want opent it again but it can't and has a error like this `c.getPositionEl().dom is undefined`
How can I do it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use hide/show, not close.  Close will destroy the dom object, hence the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Keylan's answer. You need to use window.hide instead of window.close if you want to re-use it. It is also smart to add closeAction: 'hide' to your window config.